# How to add IDNumber in sql using C# for this example output: 1300000001,1300000002,1300000003,13

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How to add `IDNumber` in SQL for this example output:

```
 1300000001,1300000002,1300000003,13......
```

The first two digits must be the last two digits of the current year, while the last 8 digits of `idnumber` must be autonumber or sequence number like `00000001,00000002,00000003,00000004..`

Because it will serve as primary key of student table..

tnx for the help..

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: There are many ways, it depends more on your situation. Please elaborate.

Comment: Reseed the identity perhaps?

Comment: I've retagged with your correct RDBMS from a comment on the answer below. Why do you have it tagged for C# as well though? Why do you need a solution for both?

Answer (score 1):

This my way of generating Id:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GEN_ID BEFORE INSERT ON DEMO FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    TEMP_ID VARCHAR(10);
    HIGHEST_NUM NUMBER;
    N NUMBER;
    NUM_OF_DIGITS NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(MAX(EMPNO),0)+1 INTO HIGHEST_NUM FROM DEMO;
    N:=HIGHEST_NUM;
    NUM_OF_DIGITS :=0;
    WHILE N!=0
    LOOP
        NUM_OF_DIGITS := NUM_OF_DIGITS + 1;
        N := TRUNC(N/10);
    END LOOP;
    TEMP_ID :='P';
    FOR I IN 1..(5-NUM_OF_DIGITS-1)
    LOOP
        TEMP_ID:=TEMP_ID||0;
    END LOOP;
    TEMP_ID := TEMP_ID||HIGHEST_NUM;
    :NEW.EMPNO := TEMP_ID;
END;
/
```

Use this logic I have a character so I am using Concatenation. This may be one way. I have tired this in Oracle not sure about C#.

This is the logic.

You need to generate a sequence where the present value depends on the previous `ID` right? So,

**first step** would be to get the last used id value. This could be used using MAX(column) then add one to the maximum number which is the serial you want which will be 1,2,3....so on.

**Step 2:** After getting the number count the number of digits present in the number

**Step 3:** You will have to generate a 10 digit number and first 2 digits will be 12/13/14 based on the year. So you need to get the last 2 digits of present year.

**Step 4:** Add 10-2[as 2 digits of year]-the number of digits in the max value of the sequence and store it as id.

**Step 5:** Concatenate the max value with id.

Comment: This has completely convinced me to never touch Oracle again. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give me sample in C#?

Comment: @BryanjayDavid: I am sorry but I have no idea of C#. I will explain the logic in the answer. You try to implement it.

Comment: @BryanjayDavid: Triggers can be used in SQL server.

Comment: @BryanjayDavid: Did you get the logic? This can be done in any programming language. This particular code can be directly used in SQL sever provided that you have same structure as I do.

Comment: @BryanjayDavid: Then may be you should consider accepting answer.